# Finding the probability involving 2 random variables.

Tags: probability

Let a random variable $Y$ represent the diameter of a shaft and a random variable $X$ represent the inside diameter of the housing that is intended to support the shaft. By design the shaft is to have diameter $99.5$ units and the housing inside diameter $100$ units. If the manufacturing process of each item is imperfect so that in fact $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $(98.5,100.5)$ and $X$ is uniformly distributed over $(99,101)$.

We need to find the probability that a particular shaft can be successfully paired with a particular housing when "successfully paired" means $X-h<Y<X$ where $h$ is a small quantity.

So we are required to calculate $P( X-h<Y<X)$.

Now here I understand that since two random variables are involved we need to fix one .

So , $P( X-h<Y<X)=\int P( X-h<Y<X|X=x)f_X(x)dx = \int P( x-h<Y<x)(\frac{1}{2})dx$.

Now next , the text I am reading , tries to calculate this $P( x-h<Y<x)$ term.

And that too assuming $h=1$. (I have no idea why 1)

$P( x-1<Y<x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{x-98.5}{2},& 99<x\leq 99.5\\ \dfrac{1}{2},& 99.5<x<100.5\\ \dfrac{100.5-(x-1)}{2},&100.5<x\leq 101\end{cases}$.

My question is since we're given $Y$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $(98.5,100.5)$ , why it has different functions for different intervals of $x$ ?

And how to establish these functions ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: When $X \sim \text{U}(98.5,100.5)$, $Y$ and $X$ overlap. If you move $X$ to the right, it stops overlapping. Same thing to the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are independently uniformly distributed, so you could draw something like this:

[image]

- The blue area corresponds to $X \le Y $
- The green area corresponds to $X-1 \lt Y \lt X$
- The red area corresponds to $Y \le X-1$

So you are interested in the green area.

For any particular value of $X$, consider a vertical line at that value:

- For $ 99 \le x \lt 99.5$ the green part of the vertical line will be shorter than the blue part, more so when $x$ is smaller
- For $ 99.5 \le x \le 100.5$ the green part of the vertical line will be equal to the sum of the blue and red parts (if it does not look like that, you are seeing an optical illusion)
- For $ 100.5 \lt x \le 101$ the green part of the vertical line will be shorter than the red part, more so when $x$ is larger

Your formulae express these explicitly

Comment: That's a very detailed answer. Thank you for that. But my doubt still remains , how to establish those functions. What I am saying is , according to me $P(x-1<Y<X) = \int_{x-1}^{x}f_Y(y)dy = \frac{1}{2}$ , since $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2}$. I am not able to see how the varying values of $x$ effect the function described above.

Comment: As $x$ varies, the proportion of the vertical line through the value $x$ which is green, i.e. $P(x-1<Y<x)$, also varies, particularly if $x \lt 99.5$ or $x \gt 100.5$